# How to combine two dataframes in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to load a csv file and shows dates, wages and percentage change. Unfortunately one of the datasets has 42 rows 3 columns the other has 41 rows 2 columns. My data file is [here](https://github.com/nerdcha/sydney-melbourne-rent/blob/master/Average_Wages.csv)

So I tried these two but no chance

```
rbind.fill(data,datadiff)
bind_rows(data,datadiff)
```

Once I try to combine them I get a result like below, second dataframe starts where the first dataframe ends
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyynA.jpg

So is there a way to show them together and tidier? Here is my code:

```
location <- read.csv("C:/Users/melik/Desktop/sydney-melbourne-rent-master/Average_Wages.csv", stringsAsFactors=T,header=TRUE)
x1 <- as.Date(location[,1],format = "%d/%m/%Y")
data <- data.frame(x1, x2 <- location[,2],x3 <- location[,3])
colnames(data) <- c("Date","Sydney Wages","Melbourne Wages")
x2diff <- diff(data[,2])/data[-nrow(data),2] * 100
x3diff <- diff(data[,3])/data[-nrow(data),3] * 100
colnames(datadiff) <- c("Sydney Difference","Melbourne Difference")
datadiff <- data.frame(x2diff,x3diff)
rbind.fill(data,datadiff)
```

Comment: Please show a small example of your data which we can copy/paste into our sessions. Present the desired output based on this data. Avoid posting images.

Comment: You can use `merge()`.. See this.. http://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html

Comment: Are you trying to bind rows or columns?

Comment: I updated my question and added my data file. @ZaheerAttar Once I use merge I got hundreds of duplicate results like this total <- merge(data[1:42,],datadiff[1:41,])

Comment: You say tidy, I say [tidyverse](http://www.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: add a dummy column of NAs named as the is missing 3rd column from your 2 column dataframe and then bind rows. But seriously, use tidyverse...

Comment: Is the date unique for every entry? If so you can add the date as identifier for merging. It is also necessary to add a NA column at the end of your datadiff-dataframe. However, you can also simply use cbind when you added the NA-row to datadiff since the order is the same in both dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the OP, adding an row with NAs to datadiff and then do a cbind is the most effective way.

```
dates = sample(seq(as.Date('2013/01/01'), as.Date('2016/01/01'), by="day"), 40)
sydneyWages = runif(n = 40, min = 1300, max = 1600)
melbourneWages = runif(n = 40, min = 1300, max = 1600)

startData = data.frame(dates, sydneyWages, melbourneWages)
x2diff <- diff(startData[,2])/startData[-nrow(startData),2] * 100
x3diff <- diff(startData[,3])/startData[-nrow(startData),3] * 100

datadiff = data.frame(x2diff, x3diff)
datadiff = rbind(datadiff, NA)

finalData = cbind(startData, datadiff)

#alternatively you can add the date to datadiff and use a merge
#this is only possible if every date is unique
datadiff = cbind(dates, datadiff)
finalData = merge(x = startData, y = datadiff, by = "dates", sort = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everyone, it works good now. Here's the latest version of my code :)

```
location <- read.csv("C:/Users/melik/Desktop/sydney-melbourne-rent-master/Average_Wages.csv", stringsAsFactors=T,header=TRUE)
x1 <- as.Date(location[,1],format = "%d/%m/%Y")
data <- data.frame(x1, x2 <- location[,2],x3 <- location[,3])
colnames(data) <- c("Date","Sydney Wages","Melbourne Wages")
x2diff <- diff(data[,2])/data[-nrow(data),2] * 100
x3diff <- diff(data[,3])/data[-nrow(data),3] * 100
datadiff <- data.frame(x2diff,x3diff)
colnames(datadiff) <- c("Sydney Difference","Melbourne Difference")
#diff(data[,2])/data[-nrow(data),2] * 100
datadiff = rbind(datadiff, NA)
finalData = cbind(data, datadiff)
finalData
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KQzU.png)